# Configuring ASP.NET in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, configuration

Is there a way to configure ASP.NET in IIS7?

I know this must be a stupid question, but in IIS7 I see an icon for ASP. Is this configuration for Classic ASP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIS 7 is very different from previous versions, especially with regards to ASP.NET.

In previous versions, the ASP.NET runtime was a separate DLL and separate process, whereas in IIS7 the ASP.NET runtime has been integrated into the core IIS server.

IIS7 does also include support for "classic" ASP, so the icon you see simply called "ASP" will be for "classic" ASP configuration.  There should be a separate section for ASP.NET configuration.

Note that all IIS7 and ASP.NET config is now done via .config files (like your machine.config and web.config in ASP.NET).

The following links should provide further information:

[IIS Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference)

[ASP.NET Integration with IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis7/)

Answer (score 2):

Check if ASP.Net feature is enabled. Here is a [description of how to verify it](http://dotnetwithme.blogspot.com/2009/01/iis-7-enabling-aspnet-on-vista.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed ASP.NET in IIS7? It might not be installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to configure?

In IIS manager there's an entire section for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Fast Way to Deploy IIS7 with .net capabilities

1. Install IIS 7.0
2. Setup Website in IIS / Add New Website e.g Default can do
3. Select default page e.g c:\mywebfolder, adjust path for default site.
4. Assign IP or run in Localhost
5. Open command prompt
   c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_iisreg.exe -i
   This will start installing preferred compilar for .aspx (v2 or v4)
6. Restart webservice in IIS
7. Congratz!!! Open your browser and watch the Aspx Web Server is Ready for Run!!