# How to leave a website on-line on the intranet

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm develping a `Call System`, and now, my boss want to try it. How May I leave my `asp.net website` on the `intranet` so he can acess and try the `website` ? I think I have to `publish` my website, but I don't know how to do that ;\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a staging server on your network which have all the necessary prerequisites installed on it like .net framework, sql, entity framework (if you are using it).

Then put the website on this server and from IIS make sure it is running with no exceptions on permissions or anything.

after that you can send the ip of the server with the application name to whoever on this network and they should be able to browse it normally.

Another fast solution will be doing the same but using your own pc (as long as you are on a network)

check these links:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0
2. [Configuring ASP.NET in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532203/configuring-asp-net-in-iis7)
3. http://forums.asp.net/t/1533954.aspx/1

Regards

Comment: There's no IIS SERVER, should I download it ? I searched the download [Here](http://www.iis.net/downloads) But I didnt find it =\

Comment: download the web platform installer and using it install IIS 7.0 or 7.5

Comment: tell me if you needed anything

Comment: Nice articles,specially that one from codeproject. I'm just having a little difficult on how to publish my site, I have to do this before start working with the ISS. Do you have experience with this ?

Comment: yes off course my friend, download Web deployment project: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19995, install it. then in your solution add new project of the type WDP then right click on it add the path to where you need to deploy it